# iOS CoreLocation Altitude

Tags: iphone, ios, core-location, altitude, cllocationdistance

Prior to iOS 4.0, `CoreLocation` was reporting altitude correctly, now it always reports as 0 ft.

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation*)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation 
{ 
    NSString *tLatitude  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%3.5f", newLocation.coordinate.latitude]; 
    NSString *tLongitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%3.5f", newLocation.coordinate.longitude];
    /*  the following returns 0 */
    NSString *tAltitude  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",    newLocation.altitude];

    /* theres more code, but it's not relevant, 
                      and this worked prior to iOS 4.0*/
    [manager stopUpdatingLocation];
}
```

Not working on Device nor Simulator, does anyone else experience this issue?

Comment: Are you testing this on a device, or on the Simulator?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you're using `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges`, which was a feature new to iOS 4.0, then you will not get altitude updates. This low-power mode only uses cell towers to figure out a user's location, and this method not report altitude.

More generally, the iPhone has three ways of figuring out your location -- cell towers, wi-fi, and GPS. You will only get altitude when the GPS is being used. So even if you set your `desiredAccuracy` setting to be really precise to force the device to use GPS, if a user is indoors the iPhone probably won't be able to get a GPS signal and will fallback to cell or wi-fi. In that case, you won't get an altitude. Also consider users who are on an iPod Touch -- it only has the ability to get a location via wi-fi, and thus also won't report an altitude.

Answer (score 2):

Two things you could try.  First of all, try setting the location manager's `desiredAccuracy` to `kCLLocationAccuracyBest`.

If that doesn't work, try removing `[manager stopUpdatingLocation];`, and put a `NSLog` in the `didUpdateToLocation` with the altitude.  Sometimes it needs to narrow down for a bit before it displays the altitude.

Comment: kCLLocationAccuracyBest has always been set, and removing stopUpdatingLocation has no effect.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Core Location Data Types Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CoreLocationDataTypesRef/Reference/reference.html):

The `CLLocationDistance` data type (the data type for altitude) is a `double`.  The formatter you are using for your `stringWithFormat` is an `integer`.  You need to cast your altitude to an `integer`, first, or use a `double` (%f) formatter.

Comment: I am converting altitude to an integer. As I stated, this worked perfectly (ie. no code changed) prior to iOS 4.0.

Comment: Also, the way I have it /gave/ me perfect altitude, used to show for example 5280 ft.

Comment: @WrightsCS have you tried the double formatter as suggested to see if that makes a difference?

Answer (score 0):

Core Location does not always report altitude immediately. I usually check for a zero altitude in my "success" delegate method. If the altitude is still 0, I keep checking, otherwise, I turn of CoreLocation.